# Hudson TestNg-plugin do not send test report mail

Tags: hudson, testng, hudson-plugins

I am running TestNg testcases through ant file which is called by hudson. I am using testng-plugin for hudson, which is getting the test-result.xml file. But it do not mail the report. I am able to see the following message in dashboard:

Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: \scripts\ant\automation\reports\testng-results.xml
Saving reports...
Processing 'C:\Users\admin.hudson\jobs\Jing_MongoDB\builds\2013-08-28_09-35-40\testng\testng-results.xml'
TestNG Reports Processing: FINISH

Is it that this plugin do not send report,or am I need to configure something else.

Comment: I don't think testng plugin will send an email with test results. It is email-ext plugin which does that. Do you also have email-ext plugin and configured it to send testng results?

Answer (score 0):

The TestNG plugin doesn't send an email report of the test results, it just displays them in the build page.

If you want to include the test results in email, take a look at the [email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin).